# Powershell Problems - Add-ADGroupMember variable not working

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

So I have a wonderfully difficult problem I'm unable to work through.  I have a list of computernames that I'm pulling from SQL to txt.  No worries there, I then import that to a variable (string array I assume?) and then for each computer name I get the Distinguished Name (DN) of the appropriate computer.  The reason is that the regular names were not matching properly in AD, when I attempted to add the computers to this group with just a regular hostname.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
    $ComputerNames = get-content  .\ComputerNames.txt 
    ForEach ($ComputerName in $Computernames) 
        {
        get-adcomputer -LDAPfilter "(CN=$Computername)" -searchscope subtree | Select-Object -Property DistinguishedName | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Append dnnames.csv
        }

    $dnnames = get-content .\dnnames.csv
    foreach ($dnname in $dnnames)
        {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity <SAM_GroupName> -Members $dnname -PassThru
        }
```

Right now I am unable to get any results from the $dnnames variable, as it does parse the value properly, but it ends up with this:

```
    Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: '"CN=<Computername>,OU=Workstations,DC=<DC>,DC=com"' under: 
    'DC=<DC>,DC=com'.
    At line:3 char:5
    +     Add-ADGroupMember -Identity <SAM_Groupname> -Members $dnname -PassT ...
    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("CN=<Computername>-...C=<DC>,DC=com":ADPrincipal) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

So I'm not certain what I'm doing wrong.   I've tried setting the variable $dnname manually with a string value and it works like a charm.  So why the heck would a get-content on the CSV (basically a comma-seperated text string) be a problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what if you add -searchbase to the query? Or drop subtree

Comment: Did you mean to use import-csv to read the csv in rather than get-content?  If so, does the first row of the csv include column headers that you want to skip?

Comment: Adil:I am using Subtree because that forces a search across the Active Directory Domain.  
Mike: I meant to use get-content as the Add-Groupmember expects a string value.  The problem with Import-CSV is that it appears as a system object, which is not useful to the add-adgroupmember command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is coming from using `out-csv` but then `get-content` instead of `import-csv`. The CSV content has quotes around the distinguishednames, and I think that's what's causing your error most directly.

The simplest change, I suggest using -ExpandProperty then Out-File (and calling it dnnames.txt).

```
$ComputerNames = Get-Content .\ComputerNames.txt
ForEach ($ComputerName in $Computernames) 
    {
    get-adcomputer -LDAPfilter "(CN=$Computername)" -searchscope subtree | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName | Out-File -Append dnnames.txt
    }

$dnnames = get-content .\dnnames.txt
foreach ($dnname in $dnnames)
    {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity <SAM_GroupName> -Members $dnname -PassThru
    }
```

That stands a good chance of working but I haven't tried it. It does seem a lot of code for what it does, though; how about avoiding the LDAPFilter, not writing to a file then reading from it, and switching to using Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership which can take multiple input from the pipeline?

That gives this:

```
$computers = Get-Content .\ComputerNames.txt | foreach { Get-ADComputer $_ }
$dnnames = $computers | Select-Object -ExpandProperty distinguishedName
$dnnames | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf "YourGroup"
```

Which you could cut the middle-men out, and squash down to:

```
gc ComputerNames.txt | %{ Get-ADComputer $_ } | select -Expand distinguishedName | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf "YourGroup"
```

Edit: Shorter version:

```
gc ComputerNames.txt | %{ (Get-ADComputer $_).sid.Value } | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf "YourGroup"
```

NB. Where you say "the regular names were not matching properly in AD, when I attempted to add the computers to this group with just a regular hostname" - the SAMAccountName for a computer defaults to the hostname with a $ after it, e.g. Win005$, and Add-ADGroupMember can work with that version. Somehow Get-ADComputer works for me finding by hostname even though the help says it needs a SAMAccountName.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.  I agree, a coworker had some time this morning to sit down with me and showed me a working piece of script.  I then worked my way backwards to understand and its definitely as you surmised the export-csv which dumps the values with quotations around it.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, eliminates exporting/importing computer names to an intermediate file:

```
$ComputerNames = Get-Content .\ComputerNames.txt
ForEach ($ComputerName in $Computernames) 
    {
    get-adcomputer -LDAPfilter "(CN=$Computername)" -searchscope subtree | % {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity <SAM_GroupName> -Members $_ 
    }
}
```

Comment: I love this answer, thank you so much for it.  I gave it to TH due to the explanation included.  However this is fantastic and much simpler than the seperated pieces.  I cottoned onto the idea of passing it in a single foreach loop last night as I was working through the problem of the output.

Comment: @SeanFalconer One thing to note with this script is it does one "Add to group" operation per computer. From the help `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` "collects all of the computer objects from the pipeline, and then adds these objects to the specified group by using one Active Directory operation." so if you have a lot of computers or are working against a remote server it might be quicker.

Comment: Thats great to know, I didn't think the principal was the way to go initially because the numbers (while large right now) should eventually be remediated.  So the number should shrink in time... or so we hope.